# Adding same object to an array

Tags: arrays, oop, object

Why is the last object only stored in my array? Please help.

This is my main method where I created the objects.

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Service sv = new Service();

    Product pd1 = new Product();
    pd1.setName("Apple");
    pd1.setCategory("Perishable");
    sv.addProduct(pd1);

    Product pd2 = new Product();
    pd2.setName("Banana");
    pd2.setCategory("Perishable");
    sv.addProduct(pd2);

    Product pd3 = new Product();
    pd3.setName("Flour");
    pd3.setCategory("Nonperishable");
    sv.addProduct(pd3);

    Product pd4 = new Product();
    pd4.setName("Mani");
    pd4.setCategory("Nonperishable");
    sv.addProduct(pd4);

    Product pd5 = new Product();
    pd5.setName("Mango");
    pd5.setCategory("Perishable");
    sv.addProduct(pd5);

    sv.reviewProduct();

}

}

public class Service {  
Product[] myProduct = new Product[10];  

public void addProduct(Product p) {
    for(int i = 0;i<myProduct.length;i++) {
        //myProduct[i] = new Product();
        myProduct[i] = p;   
    }
}

public void reviewProduct() {
    //for(int i=0;i<myProduct.length;i++) {
    System.out.println(myProduct[1].getName());
    System.out.println(myProduct[1].getCategory());
    //}
}
}
```

Comment: code formatting

Answer (score 0):

```
public void reviewProduct() {
    //for(int i=0;i<myProduct.length;i++) {
    System.out.println(myProduct[1].getName());
    System.out.println(myProduct[1].getCategory());
    //}
}
```

You are using myProduct[1] in you loop which only grabs index 1. You need to use myProduct[i]

Answer (score 0):

Your `addProduct` function overwrites the previous elements in the array since it fills the array with the same element.

You should use a [List](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html) instead, and `add` elements into it. You can convert it into an array later if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

As Alex mentioned, you should use list.

Here is the fix for your service class:

```
public class Service {  
    List<Product> myProducts = new ArrayList<Product>();    

    public void addProduct(Product p) {
    myProduct.add(p);   
    }

    public void reviewProduct() {
    for(int i=0;i<myProduct.length;i++) {
        System.out.println(myProduct[i].getName());
        System.out.println(myProduct[i].getCategory());
    }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!